# Select Rows with Longest Unique Strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-like, exists

I'm trying to figure out how to select a subset of rows from a table, with the longest unique string for each "parent" string. I'll provide table examples below and my code that didn't work.

Current Table:

| Name | SalePrice |
| --- | --- |
| NorthAmerica\US\Northeast\NewYork | 8576 |
| NorthAmerica\US\Northeast | 2598 |
| SouthAmerica\Brazil | 1348 |
| SouthAmerica\Chile\NorthEast | 9726 |
| SouthAmerica\Chile | 4412 |
| NorthAmerica\Canada\Ontario | 3894 |
| NorthAmerica\Canada | 6321 |

Desired Output:

| Name | SalePrice |
| --- | --- |
| NorthAmerica\US\Northeast\NewYork | 8576 |
| SouthAmerica\Brazil | 1348 |
| SouthAmerica\Chile\NorthEast | 9726 |
| NorthAmerica\Canada\Ontario | 3894 |

Originally, I thought I could apply some form of logic based off the number of backslashes (

```
example: SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Name LIKE '%\\%'
```

). However, this logic doesn't work because some names furthest branch may only have 1 backslash while others may have 3+.

Code to generate test table is below and any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

```
create table t1( 
[name] varchar(60), 
[saleprice] int  );


insert into t1 values ('NorthAmerica\US\Northeast\NewYork',8576);
insert into t1 values ('NorthAmerica\US\Northeast',2598);
insert into t1 values ('SouthAmerica\Brazil',1348);
insert into t1 values ('SouthAmerica\Chile\NorthEast',9726);
insert into t1 values ('SouthAmerica\Chile',4412);
insert into t1 values ('NorthAmerica\Canada\Ontario',3894);
insert into t1 values ('NorthAmerica\Canada',6321);
```

Comment: a normalized relational structure would make the query very easy

Comment: @nbk I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad  and also storing hierarchical data in databases would be a good reading start

Comment: What if there are ties? For example, if you add "NorthAmerica\US\Northeast\Philadelphia", what would your expected outcome be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the operator `LIKE` with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM t1 AS t2
  WHERE t2.name LIKE t1.name + '_%'
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0f7645a5414053c130745603ed091bfe).

Comment: This worked perfectly, now I need to work on understanding it

Comment: @2020db9 in simple words the query returns a name x if there is no other longer name y that starts with x.

Comment: @2020db9 maybe `t2.name LIKE t1.name + '\%'` is more suitable. Try it.

Comment: both approaches seem to work as intended